# CAShapeLayer is appearing before Views

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have two views between which is located resizable line (view with CAShapeLayer). The problem that I'm facing with is that despite the animation on layer, it is appearing faster than views are changing. I know that animation of layer is completely different, but can't understand where is my fault. Please tell me if I made something wrong.

Here is the code of my layer's animation (used "strokeStart" as well, but it didn't worked):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let centerX = bounds.size.width / 2
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: centerX, y: 0), CGPoint(x: centerX, y: frame.height)])
    dashedLayer.path = path
    dashedLayer.frame = bounds

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = height
    animation.toValue = bounds.size.height
    height = bounds.size.height
    animation.duration = 0.3
    dashedLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Code of views' animation (because of modifying views, I animate layoutIfNeeded):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one easy way to deal with this is to animate the constraint constant like this:

```
  @IBOutlet weak  var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {

        self. heightConstaint.constant = 300 // This constant is the height of top big view. 

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()}
```

There is another view where the CAShapeLayer lies in. I call it `line View` . Its height should be constrained as same as the height of the `top big view`.

In the `line view`, you can add animations. This should be similar to your implementation.

```
   override func didMoveToSuperview() {
     super.didMoveToSuperview()
     dashedLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
     layer.addSublayer(dashedLayer)
     height = bounds.size.height
   }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let centerX = bounds.size.width / 2
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: centerX, y: 0), CGPoint(x: centerX, y: frame.height)])
    dashedLayer.path = path
    dashedLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    dashedLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = height / bounds.size.height
    animation.toValue = 1.0 
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    height = bounds.size.height
    animation.duration = 3.0
    dashedLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

It's expanding here. You may adapt the code to contract by yourself.

[image]

The following is with the reversing animation.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    dashedLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(dashedLayer)
    height = bounds.size.height
      clipsToBounds = true
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let centerX = bounds.size.width / 2
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: centerX, y: 0), CGPoint(x: centerX, y: max(height , bounds.size.height) )])
    dashedLayer.path = path
    dashedLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    dashedLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    if (height < bounds.size.height){
    animation.fromValue = height / bounds.size.height
        animation.toValue = 1.0}

    else {
        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = bounds.size.height / height}


    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    height = bounds.size.height
    animation.duration = 3
    dashedLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: it works, but when it comes to backward animation, it behaves like before

Comment: I add the reversing one now.

Comment: Why not just animate the path instead of the stroke?

Comment: He may need some background image for the path

Comment: @E.Coms thank you so much! already tried to do in similar way except of max() in CGPoint

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems with your current code. At the moment you're changing the path without animation, so it updates immediately. Also `strokeEnd` takes a value of 0 to 1, so right now your path always has a complete stroke.

You should animate the path change instead of the stroke.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let centerX = bounds.size.width / 2
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: centerX, y: 0), CGPoint(x: centerX, y: frame.height)])
    dashedLayer.path = path
    dashedLayer.frame = bounds

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    animation.duration = 0.3
    animation.fromValue = dashedLayer.path
    animation.toValue = path
    dashedLayer.add(animation, forKey: "pathAnimation")
}
```